# How to run threads asynchrounously but get results in synchronous way without using lock, countdownlatch, or synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I have used an `executorService`. The pool size is 5, and I have initialized
an array  `final int[] count = {0};` and AtomicInteger `at  = new AtomicInteger(0);`

Then I am iterating this for 10000 times and in every iteration I am doing
`count[0]++`
`at.incrementAndGet()`

But why I am not getting same value at the end?

I have used locks, synchronized block, `awaitTermination` with big delay, `countdownlatch`, but I don't want all this. Is there a way that I can achieve the same result?

```
class AsyncExecutorApplicationTests {
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Test
    void check() {
        try {
            final int[] countt = {0};
//          Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
                executorService.execute(()-> {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        countt[0]++;
                        count.incrementAndGet();
                        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount()+"-----" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "----" + count.get() + "-----" + countt[0]);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                );
                executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // blocks/waits for certain interval as specified
                executorService.shutdown();
            }
            Assertions.assertEquals(1000, count.get());
            Assertions.assertEquals(1000, countt[0]);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you check the value at the end, or the declaration of `countt` and `count`, or the end of your for loop.

Comment: `count.compareAndSet` may fail and you have to retry. In your code, you don't retry.

Comment: Note that the increment operator (`++`) is not atomic. So, calling `count[0]++` from multiple threads is not safe and thus can give you unpredictable results. And your use of `compareAndSet` is also not "safe" either, because you don't try again if the increment fails (you probably should just be using `incrementAndGet()` or `getAndIncrement()` and just ignore the return value). Also, an `ExecutorService` won't terminate before `shutdown()` is called, so your `awaitTermination` will always wait 10 milliseconds no matter what, because you don't call `shutdown()` until after.

Comment: And you use a new thread pool for each task. You should reuse the thread pool. Also, checking the result in the loop is plain wrong.

Comment: Now you have a catch with no matching try!

Comment: there is a try above the loop

Comment: @tgdavies what can i do to achieve exact results 
i thing the array is taking slightly more time than atomic integer
also i cannot change the data structure

Comment: okay sure let me update the code

Comment: @Slaw  if i am using locks or countdownlatch or even if i increase the await time my testcases are passed 
But i want all the threads to work concurrently without any sort of lock 
if the iteration is bigger i sometime get race condition

Comment: To get the result you want, you can swap the `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` lines, and increase the `awaitTermination` timeout to 200ms. But I don't really understand what you think your code does/should do.

Comment: @tgdavies  thank you for your help I am a newbie I am still learning all the the concepts I am trying to find a way how I can make count[0]++ work same as atomic I would take your advices and make changes accordingly