# is it possible to make an non atomic variable thread safe without using locks or synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, threadpool

I want to run this asynchronously but all no thread locking , no syncronization also awaitTermination timeout should not be increased.

```
    @Test
    void arrayCheck() throws InterruptedException {
        final int[] count = {0};
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i <10000; i++) {
            executorService.execute(() ->
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    count[0]++;
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"----"+count[0]+"---");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            executorService.awaitTermination(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }
        Assertions.assertEquals(10000,count[0]);
    }
```

i have used atomic variables but i have to use array only

Comment: Not hugely different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76685093/how-to-run-threads-asynchrounously-but-get-results-in-synchronous-way-without-us) which you could have edited based on the comments or deleted.

Comment: what can i do to solve this problem @DuncG i have made changes

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible.

Comment: (Note that the `AtomicInteger` implementation in Java relies on CAS - compare and swap - or a similar instruction provided by the hardware.  `volatile` semantics are not sufficient.)

Comment: You need to explain the problem properly. Even if you resolve updating the counters the final total is never going to be right as you await termination for 10ms but may have 5x runnable each requiring 200ms before they end

Comment: i want that when threads are taking over count situation like deadlock or race condition should not occur
also the count after 10000 iteration should be 10000 @DuncG

Comment: If `count` wasn't an array it could be `volatile`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to make the `++` operator thread safe without synchronization or locking. [This is not an atomic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25168062/29470), and requires three sub-steps:

1. reading the current value of the variable
2. adding one to that value
3. storing the result back in that variable

In a multi-threaded context, these operations can be interleaved with other threads, meaning that the value of the variable can change between step 1 and step 3 above resulting in a lost update because the same count is stored by more than one thread.

In addition to that, it is *never* thread safe to access and modify an array concurrently in Java without taking measures to ensure visibility of updates to other threads. See [Java volatile array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5173614/29470) for details.

The only way to perform an atomic, thread-safe increment operation without locking in Java is to use classes from [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), such as [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).